# Pythonic way to read 3 csv files in a fucntion?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

```
def production(csvfile):
    # do something with csvfile
    print csvfile

production("somecsvfile.csv")
```

I want to pass 3 csv file files and the program should give the output for it.currently i have given one csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function add the following

```
fileList = csvfiles.split(",")
for files in filesList:
    data = read_csv(csvfile)
    ....
    ....


production("rswm20160901C.csv,rswm20160901E.csv,rswm20160901D.csv")
```

or

```
import sys
def production(csvfile)
......
......

fileList = sys.argv[1:] # pass the functions in command line
for f in fileList:
    production(f)
```

Comment: you have passed csv files as a string. is there any way to pass them as separated files ?

Comment: This is neither pythonic way nor a good programming practice.

Comment: @Dheeraj you have two options as production(['rswm20160901C.csv','rswm20160901C.csv','rswm20160901C.csv']) or pass by arguments production(sys.argv)

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to over-complicate situations.
This should do:

```
def production(csvfile)
......
......

fileList = ['a.csv','b.csv','c.csv']
for f in fileList:
    production(f)
```

Comment: FYI: I don't think there is anything pythonic about it. Just proper function use.

Comment: I am new to programming. Thats why this is a bit complicated for me. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: No problemo.  Just accept the question if you think it solves your question.

Comment: I think it is wrong approach, because if need add another file function has to be modified.

Comment: fileList variable initialization is just example, it could be initialized from whatever source, and that will be independent of the loop.
May be I am missing something. Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use python `*args` argument unpacking that can accept arbitrary number of arguments. It will works for any number of arguments

```
def production(*csvfile):
    for csv in csvfile:
        # do something with csvfile
        print(csv)

production("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
# code above will printout 
# file1.csv 
# file2.csv 
# file3.csv
production("file1.csv")
# just print out 
# file1.csv
```

If you want it to be exact 3 input files, you can either define 3 inputs like below or 1 list input which will works for any list length also

```
def production(csvfile1, csvfile2, csvfile3):
    for csv in [csvfile1, csvfile2, csvfile3]:
        # do something with csvfile
        print(csv)
```